# Convert string (without separator) to date

Tags: php, date, parsing

I want to convert my string to date, I know that I can use `DateTime::createFromFormat`, my problem is that there is no separator in `$d`

```
<?php $d = "01122015"; ?>
```

expected output :

```
01/12/2015
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use format method of it to format as per your wish,

```
$d = "01122015";
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('dmY', $d);
echo $date->format('d/m/Y');
```

**Output:-**

```
01/12/2015
```

Comment: Of course, quite, I didn't know that we could not put separator in `createFromFormat('dmY'...`. Thanks I accept the answer in few minutes

Answer (score 1):

Also you can achieve it by

```
$a = '01122015';
$b = '';
$cnt = 0;
$otheCnt= 0;
for($i=0;$i<strlen($a);$i++){
        $cnt++;
        $b .= $a[$i];
        if($cnt==2 && $otheCnt < 2){
            $otheCnt++;
            $b .= '/';
            $cnt = 0;
        }
}
echo $b;
```

**Output:**

```
01/12/2015
```

Comment: Thanks you for your time, the @Rahul solution is more simple and clean, Thanks again

Comment: welcome :) , yes, you are right.